# Reading CSV file results in list index out of range

Tags: python, csv, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a csv file with numerous columns and some columns have more rows than others.  I am trying to read certain columns and extract those columns to a different csv file.  However, I keep getting list index out of range because the columns I'm reading are shorter than the other columns in the csv file.

```
import csv
import os
import os.path

'Open csv directory to extract data from'
path = 'S://Raw Data/VehicleData/'               

'Get file names and print number of files in the directory'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]
print(files)
print(len(files))

'Start loop to scan through files in directory'
for j in range(len(files)):

'determine name of file and the output name of the file'
name = files[j]
print(name)

'path to file to open'
fpath = os.path.join(path, files[j])

    if files[j].endswith(".csv"):
        nameout = 'VehicleN3STPData' + '.csv'
        with open (fpath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
            testcsv = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
            with open (nameout,'a+',newline='') as outfile:
                writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                for row in testcsv:
                    my_row = []
                    my_row.append(row[59])
                    my_row.append(row[111])
                    my_row.append(row[120])
                    print(my_row)
                    writer.writerow(my_row)
                outfile.close()    
        csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional statement to check for length or you need a try & except clause depending on your intended behavior.

Here's an example of using a conditional statement that preserves the column values as blanks if they don't exist.

Instead of:

```
my_row.append(row[59]) 
my_row.append(row[111]) 
my_row.append(row[120])
```

Do:

```
for col_num in [59, 111, 120]:
    my_row.append(row[col_num] if len(row) > col_num else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, here is the final code that worked, removing the header with islice, using your conditional statement, and then removing the blank lines with if any(my_row)  thanks!!

```
    if files[j].endswith(".csv"):
    nameout = 'VehicleN3STPData' + '.csv'
    with open (fpath, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        testcsv = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
        with open (nameout,'a+',newline='') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in islice(testcsv,3,None):
                    my_row = []
                    for col_num in [59,111,120]:
                        my_row.append(row[col_num] if len(row) > col_num else '')
                    if any(my_row):
                        writer.writerow(my_row)
            outfile.close()    
    csvfile.close()enter code here
```